# Shiny - how to prevent plotting if no data is selected with the slider

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I want to plot a plotly 3D graph inside my Shiny App, but only the data with values that are in the range of input range slider. However I want to prevent plotting when there are no values in the range of the sliders - currently this causes the following error when there are no inputs:

```
Warning: Error in UseMethod: no applicable method for 'plotly_build' applied       
to an object of class "NULL"
```

or in the example code:

```
Error in : length(Lab) == 3L is not TRUE
```

This is an example code which has a similar error as original problem:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

d = diamonds[1:100,]

ui = fluidPage(
headerPanel("Data"),

sliderInput(inputId="slider", label = "Choose a range", value =c(0,max(d$price)),
          min = 0,max = max(d$price)),

# saves space for the plot in the user interface. Id allows communication
plotlyOutput(outputId="trendPlot", width="100%", height=800)

)

server = function(input, output)
{
NROF = reactiveValues(test = 1)

output$trendPlot= renderPlotly({
d_sub=d[d$price >= input$slider[1] & d$price <= input$slider[2],]
NROF = nrow(d) 
if(NROF != 0)
{
  plot_ly(d_sub, x=d_sub$cut, y=d_sub$color, z=factor(d_sub$color),
          type='scatter3d', mode='markers',
          sizemode='diameter', size=d_sub$price, color=d_sub$price,colors = 'Set1')

}
})
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

SOLUTION: I've made a mistake using reactive values - it should have been NROF$TEST

Comment: please edit and simplify your question by proviing a reproducible example. e.g. providing a fully executable shiny code (server and UI) only including your problem.

Comment: Ok, the error/warning comes from the color parameter of the plotly function. If one takes d$color it will render it (although incorrect color will be used upon filtering when one observes the color),so the question remains the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like `req()` or `validate()` are what you're looking for:

http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/req.html

http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/validation.html

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

d <- diamonds[1:100,]

ui <- fluidPage(
  headerPanel("Data"),
  sliderInput(inputId="slider",
              label = "Choose a range",
              value =c(0,max(d$price)),
              min = 0,max = max(d$price)),
  # saves space for the plot in the user interface. Id allows communication
  plotlyOutput(outputId="trendPlot",
               width="100%", height=800)

)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$trendPlot <- renderPlotly({
    d_sub <- d[d$price >= input$slider[1] & d$price <= input$slider[2],]
    req(nrow(d_sub) > 0)
    # validate(need(nrow(d_sub) > 0, "No data selected!"))

    plot_ly(d_sub, x=d_sub$cut, y=d_sub$color, 
            z=factor(d_sub$color), type='scatter3d', 
            mode='markers', sizemode='diameter', 
            size=d_sub$price, color=d_sub$price,
            colors = 'Set1')
  })
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Comment: Well this is awkward, actually both of you gave me extremely good feedback, so not sure which one to accept as answer :) Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce it. My suggestion is that there was a small typo (you meant `NROF = nrow(d_sub)`  instead of `NROF = nrow(d)`). Plus, you did not include any return value for the `else` case.

Does this help you?

```
server = function(input, output)
{
  NROF = reactiveValues(test = 1)

  output$trendPlot= renderPlotly({
    d_sub=d[d$price >= input$slider[1] & d$price <= input$slider[2],]
    NROF = nrow(d_sub)
    if(NROF != 0)
    {
      plot_ly(d_sub, x=d_sub$cut, y=d_sub$color, z=factor(d_sub$color),
              type='scatter3d', mode='markers',
              sizemode='diameter', size=d_sub$price, color=d_sub$price,colors = 'Set1')

    } else {
      plot_ly(type='scatter3d')
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Well this is awkward, actually both of you gave me extremely good feedback, so not sure which one to accept as answer :) Thank you so much!

Comment: Also, you as well as I have missed the fact that it should have been used like:
NROF$test = ....